# Memory Calculations in C

Tags: c, linux, memory

I am trying to pull the actual memory of the computer and was wondering why there is a discrepancy between

sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES) * sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) and /proc/meminfo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(){
  unsigned long long ram = (sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES) * sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE));
  printf("%lli = ram\n", ram);
  return 0;
}
```

Output = 8325185536

8325185536 Bytes = 8.325185536 Gb

```
User > cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8130064 kB
```

8130064kB = 8.130064Gb

0.195121536Gb off?

Comment: `1GB = 1024MB = 1024*1024KB = 1024*1024*1024*1024 Bytes`   Except when it [isn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)

Comment: Note: us an "%llu" format for printing an *unsigned* value.

Comment: Buy 1000 MB of RAM, and get 24 MB for free!

Comment: Well it appears Google does drop the 24 and I wasn't paying attention =S Thanks for the help guys.  8325185536 Bytes = 8130064KB

Answer (score 2):

For historical reasons, when reporting memory operating systems use units based on powers of 2 even though they don't use the correct SI prefixes for those units. So when it says "8130064 kB", it means 8,130,064 [KiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte), or 8,325,185,536 bytes.